# Why isn't the word "religion" mentioned in the description for some of the religion-based Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, support, site-description, religion-sites

Right now, the only Stack Exchange site that mentions the word "religion" in its description is [Hinduism Stack Exchange](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com).

Neither [Buddhism Stack Exchange](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com), [Christianity Stack Exchange](https://christianity.stackexchange.com), [Islam Stack Exchange](https://islam.stackexchange.com), nor [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com) mention it in their descriptions.

The keyword should be mentioned in the description of those sites, to assist with search. (I guess this is the organizer/librarian in me.)

Comment: There is also a Biblical Hermeneutics site (also without religion in it’s description).

Comment: @MEEwasthemissingbracket I know about that site, but I wasn't sure if I should include it in 'religion' sites, per se. [@Sonic: thanks for the edit.]